# How can I use the value of one variable when i declare another

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery but getting there. I am stuck trying to add the value from one var to when I declare another.

Here is my code -

```
var selected = jQuery(this).val(); 

var vt = jQuery('.details-tcs').find('input:radio:checked').val();
```

I need to use the first var 'selected' with a value of 'AI' and add it to the second var 'vt' so it looks like -

```
var vt = jQuery('.details-tcs.AI').find('input:radio:checked').val();
```

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: simply use string concatenation: `jQuery('.details-tcs.' + selected)`

Comment: Don't waste your keyboard. Wrap in a DOM ready like `jQuery(function($){ /* Use the $ alias here and save some fingernails */ })`

Comment: Calvin - no joy - error says 'Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .details-tcs.'

Comment: Not really sure what u mean Roko

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```html
var vt = jQuery(`.details-tcs.${selected}`).find('input:radio:checked').val();
```

Comment: Just be wary there is no IE support for template literals https://caniuse.com/#search=Template%20Literals

Comment: Is there another way i could do it so it works in IE?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first add event listener on radio buttons because empty values can cause errors.Eg.

```
document.querySelector("."+val) // val is null when page loads
```

Attach event listener and then use string concatenation:

```
//var vt =""; //use global variables when using values outside of functions. Also Modify using functions
jQuery(".details-tcs input:radio").change(function(){
    var selected = jQuery(this).val();
    var vt = jQuery('.details-tcs').find('input:radio:checked').val();
    vt = jQuery('.details-tcs.'+vt).find('input:radio:checked').val(); // modify previous variable. Don't declare again
});
```